# Verificar que existe registro en tabla MySQL antes de actualizar

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

He logrado actualizar un campo de una columna en mi tabla MySQL y el usuario debe colocar el ID de la tabla.

Lo que quiero lograr es que si el usuario introduce un ID que no existe pueda salir un alert diciéndole al usuario que ese ID no existe.

Mi código:

```
include("conexion.php");
require_once 'conexion.php';

$estado  = $_POST["estado"];
$npedido = $_POST["npedido"];
$query   = "UPDATE creadas SET estado='$estado' WHERE npedido='$npedido' ";
if ($db->query($query)) {
    echo "<script> alert('Usted ha cambiado el estado del pedido, por favor ejecute el delivery');
                        location.href = 'dashboard.php';
                        </script>";
} else {
    echo "Error al Registrar, vuevla a intentarlo" . mysqli_error($db);
}
```

Comment: Saludos. Considero 2 formas de hacerlo; una de ellas es que verifiques primero si el `ID` existe en la tabla Catálogo/Padre y de no existir denegar el UPDATE o INSERT. Otra es que crees los `CONSTRAINT'  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html y desde luego cachar el error para mostrarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todo lo que necesitas es hacer una consulta para seleccionar el pedido. Si el total de filas encontradas es igual a 1, quiere decir que sí existe.

```
include("conexion.php");
require_once 'conexion.php';

$estado  = $_POST["estado"];
$npedido = $_POST["npedido"];

// Verificar pedido
$query   = "SELECT estado FROM creadas WHERE npedido='$npedido' ";
$result = $db->query($query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    // Sí existe el pedido
    $query   = "UPDATE creadas SET estado='$estado' WHERE npedido='$npedido' ";
    if ($db->query($query)) {
        echo "<script> alert('Usted ha cambiado el estado del pedido, por favor ejecute el delivery');
                        location.href = 'dashboard.php';
                        </script>";
    } else {
        echo "Error al Registrar, vuevla a intentarlo" . mysqli_error($db);
    }
} else {
    // No existe el pedido
    // Aquí tu mensaje de error
}
```

Referencia: [mysqli: Obtener número de filas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Comment: Excelente, me funcionó y también entendí el "if" muchisimas gracias...!!!